# How would one go about implementing the stock iOS emoji keyboard programmatically?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

It seems there's two main sections:
[image]

Let's call them `emojiCollection` and `bottomBar`. `bottomBar` seems simple enough, a `UIStackView` that's horizontal, that contains a back to main keyboard button, backspace, and a bunch of categories in the middle.

`emojiCollection` is trickier for me to understand, and my questions are:

1) how would one have "sections" of emojis, where there is a title at the top that remains in place until you get to the next section. Is this all just one UICollectionView?

2) How would you go about highlighting the section in `bottomBar` to identify which section you're in.

3) Seeing that it's horizontal and extends past the screen, would it be placed in a UIView that has some width proportional to the amount of rows, or would it automatically keep growing?

EDIT: To answer  Losiowaty's question, this is how I would like to build it:[image]

Comment: What have you tried yourself? What research did you do? Can you show your code and explain what didn't work?

Comment: This is a hierarchical question from a top level design. Rather than start hammering out code that requires severe refactoring, I wanted to know if anyone has the knowledge and foresight of its implementation. I have looked into UICollections and can create a collection if it were from the storyboard, but injecting this as a subView is a mystery to me. My research was reading all of apple APIs related to this view and its functionality. I prefer to have a blueprint to begin doing this vs trial and error. A top level explanation is sufficient for me.